# Using JavaScript to show and hide PHP echoed XML data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml

I'm using PHP to echo out 50 video id's from an XML file. I use the video id's to embed 50 YouTube videos into my website. This works fine but I need to isolate the videos two at a time. I don't want the user to see all fifty videos at once. I want them to see two, then click next, see another two, then maybe click back, etc. etc.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$url = "http://www.theURLofmyXML.blah";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$i = 0;

while ($i < 49) {

$title = (string) $xml->query->results->item[$i]->title;
$videoid = (string) $xml->query->results->item[$i]->id;
$explanation = (string) $xml->query->results->item[$i]->explanation;

$i = $i + 1;

echo $title."<br />";
echo '<iframe width="400" height="225" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$videoid.'?rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br/>';
echo $explanation."<br /><br />";

}
```

So I think the best thing to do is echo all fifty items to the page inside divs labeled 0 to 49...then use JavaScript to hide all divs except 0 and 1 until you click a next button and it switches to hiding everything except 2 and 3...and so on...

But I'm not sure how to do that in JavaScript/jQuery. I think using .show() and .hide() would work but I'm not sure of the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following HTML structure:

```
    <a href="#" class="prev-video-row">Previous videos</a>
    <div class="video-row active">
      <!-- First couple videos -->
    </div>
    <!-- Loop through all videos, writing the other rows -->
    <div class="video-row">
      <!-- Last couple videos -->
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="next-video-row">Next videos</a>
```

**Note**: Use the `active` class only in the first video row to show them by default on the page load.

With CSS, hide all `.video-row` (using: `display:none;`) and show only `.video-row.active` (using: `display:block;`).

Finally, use the following Javascript (jQuery needed) to navigate between video rows:

```
    jQuery('.prev-video-row').click(function (event)
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      var prev = jQuery('.video-row.active').prev();
      if (prev.length)
      {
        jQuery('.video-row').removeClass('active');
        prev.addClass('active');
      }
    });
    jQuery('.next-video-row').click(function (event)
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      var next = jQuery('.video-row.active').next();
      if (next.length)
      {
        jQuery('.video-row').removeClass('active');
        next.addClass('active');
      }
    });
```

Comment: +1 this despite my answer as it answers the question in the way the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly speaking, I don't think it's great to have 50 videos embedding in a page - regardless of visibility or not; simply because they will be processed by the browser despite not being visible. (Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, but the browser is going to see, and process, the whole DOM - and just apply the styles to the "hidden" bits.)

Gustavo Straube has given a really good answer on how to do this if you want to have 50 elements in the DOM despite the effects it may have on both browser and bandwith.

I'd probably go for something more along the lines of parsing the XML, storing all the data as JSON then dynamically updating the DOM with jQuery from HTML supplied with a templating framework like Mustache.js.

```
/* Generate JSON */
$url = "http://www.theURLofmyXML.blah";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$i = 0;
$json = array();

while ($i < 49) {

$arr['title'] = (string) $xml->query->results->item[$i]->title;
$arr['videoid'] = (string) $xml->query->results->item[$i]->id;
$arr['explanation'] = (string) $xml->query->results->item[$i]->explanation;

$json[] = $arr;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Then, in your markup have something like the below, just to initialise your first x videos - in this example 10..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var template = '{{$title}}<br /><iframe width="400" height="225"'
       + 'src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{$videoid}}?rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br/>'
       + '{{explanation}}<br /><br />';
    var html = '';
    var i=0;

    for(; i<10; i++){
        var item = json[i];
        html += Mustache.to_html(template, item);
    }
    $('#videos').html(html); //where #videos is a div to contain your videos
```

Next up have an anchor (in this example #next) to get the next 10 videos..

```
    $('#next').click(function(){
        /* template, i and json are still in scope! */
        var j = i+10;
        for(; i<j; i++){
            var item = json[i];
            html += Mustache.to_html(template, item);
        }
        $('#videos').html(html); //where #videos is a div to contain your videos
    });
```

The advantage of this is it's also easy to do a previous anchor...

```
    $('#prev').click(function(){
        /* template, i and json are still in scope! */
        var j = i -10;
        i -= 20; //10 for the current page, 10 for the start of the previous page
        for(; i<j; i++){  //rebuild div content of previous page
            var item = json[i];
            html += Mustache.to_html(template, item);
        }
        $('#videos').html(html);
    });
```

Just to re-iterate, this is an **alternative solution** - I've suggested it as using JSON is a little bit more lightweight and more flexible than XML, and it also removes the requirement for having 50 DOM elements that aren't in use at one time. There may be a reason you've chosen the implementation that you have, but it's not the implementation I would take if I was given this problem!

Comment: Haha, that's amazing. After using Gustavo Straube's solution (which worked fine) I did indeed realize that all 50 videos had to be rendered to the DOM and it slowed things down far too much. Thank you very much for your solution!

Comment: haha, glad to help! I will admit, it was pure guess work as to whether the effect would be noticable or not; but I figured I'd post anyway! I +1ed Gustavo's answer as it was related to the question though. I havent checked that code through fully, but I can't see any major errors! If there are, just post a comment on here and I'll look it over. :) Good luck dude!

Answer (score 1):

For html like:

```
<div id="section0"></div>
```

Your jquery would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#section0').show();
    $('#section1').show();

    $('#nextButton').click(function(e){        
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#section0').hide();
        $('#section1').hide();
        $('#section2').show();
        $('#section3').show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

And so on...